# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, определенный текст записался не в форме, а на редакторе?

Tags: c#

Как в C# сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, определенный текст записался не в форме программы, а на редакторе, где работает пользователь?
Например я в браузере щас пишу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, текст записался не в форму, а в браузере где я только что писал, или же в текстовом документе, ну короче в редакторной среде где я сейчас пишу? Надеюсь смог донести свои мысли. Возможно такое и как? Кто сможет помочь?

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите передать сообщение другой программе? Написанной не Вами?

Comment: ну например я могу сделать так: сделать событие на нажатие кнопки и написать: textbox1.text = "Hello World", и он появится на форме и в текстбоксе. А я хочу выйти за рамки формы. Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, эта запись появилась не в тектбоксе, а в редакторной части программы, на котором сейчас работает пользователь @Modus

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону функций `WinAPI` `SendMessage` и `PostMessage`.

Comment: Добавлю, что для таких случаев существует класс System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.